# Label is set before string is formatted

Tags: c#, winforms

So i am creating an x and o's game and i have a label which shows who's turn it is ( `WhosTurnLabel`) but when i try to format their chosen name into a string it only assigns the string to the label and not the formatted version.

```
WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{playerXName}'s Turn";
```

`playerXName` is taken from a text box input.

```
game.playerXName = PlayerXName.Text;
```

When i am debugging and hover over the `$` it shows the string i want the label to be, but when i check the form and hover my mouse over `WhosTurnLabel.Text` it only shows "'s Turn".

I assign the names to variables in another class then open that form up here:

```
Game game;
game = new Game();

game.playerXName = PlayerXName.Text;
game.playerOName = PlayerOName.Text;

game.Show();
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

p.s: im still learning c# and really i need someone to check my programs code, i think there may be a few hiccups

Comment: Please also post the place where it is taken from the text box input...

Comment: i have edited it to include that

Comment: sounds like PlayerOName.Text is null or empty

Comment: nope it is not when i check it it has the correct value assigned to it

Comment: When are you setting WhoseTurnLabel.Text? Maybe you need to set it in an event when PlayerOName's value changes

Comment: @Atlntic well if it wasnt null or empty then it would be in the label

Comment: C# does not have text boxes or labels, so please tag your question with the appropriate UI framework tag (`winform`, `wpf`, etc.). You probably also need more context.

Comment: Can you also show the code where `playerXName` is being set.

Comment: What happens if you do directly this: ` WhosTurnLabel.Text = PlayerOName.Text + "'s Turn";` ?

Comment: i am getting PlayerOname from a different form so i assign it to a variable in the main form i want to run

Comment: Have you tried:
WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{playerXName.Text}'s Turn";

Comment: You say you read playerXname, but then show code setting playerOname. Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: yes i edited it now

Comment: I suggest rewriting it the old-fashioned way (`WhosTurnLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}'s Turn", playerXName)`) and making sure it compiles and works correctly. After you have it working that way, you can put it back if you want.

Comment: Please check the answer I provided, I tested it locally and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing in the values for playerXName and playerOName as parameters to the Game form constructor?  This worked fine for me:

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    public string playerXName,
                  playerOName;

    public Game(string player1, string player2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        playerXName = player1;
        playerOName = player2;

        WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{playerXName}'s Turn";
    }
}
```

I just assigned the label text attribute in the constructor, however, playerXName and playerOName are fields in the object and should be accessible to any methods and event handlers within the Game class.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the value, at least at the point the string is created is null, empty, or undefined.

Something else to look into, though I am unsure without seeing more of the code, but should

```
WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{playerXName}'s Turn";
```

be

```
WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{game.playerXName}'s Turn";
```

I don't know it would have compiled or not thrown an error in that case, but just something that stood out to me.

But to sum it up, the string is definitely empty or null, at least at the point the string is created.

Comment: Is the game object before or after the label's are set?

Comment: it is after. I have a window that takes names then you press start and it opens the main game window

Answer (score 0):

Add a Game_Shown event and put `WhosTurnLabel.Text = $"{playerXName}'s Turn";` in there

Comment: To add an event got to form's design view, view the properties, select the lightning bolt at the top and double-click in the  "Shown" row.